# Why won't Google Tapas accept my Table? TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, typeerror, huggingface

I think the issue is related with the following code. I took a lot of it from a tutorial on Tapas so I'm not exactly sure what the code is meant to do besides embed the information in the table which has been formatted to a string.

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

# we will use batches of 64
batch_size = 64

for i in tqdm(range(0, len(processed_tables), batch_size)):
    # find end of batch
    i_end = min(i+batch_size, len(processed_tables))
    # extract batch
    batch = processed_tables[i:i_end]
    # generate embeddings for batch
    emb = retriever.encode(batch).tolist()
    # create unique IDs ranging from zero to the total number of tables in the dataset
    ids = [f"{idx}" for idx in range(i, i_end)]
    # add all to upsert list
    to_upsert = list(zip(ids, emb))
    # upsert/insert these records to pinecone
    _ = index.upsert(vectors=to_upsert)

# check that we have all vectors in index
index.describe_index_stats()
```

Output

```
{'dimension': 768,
 'index_fullness': 0.0,
 'namespaces': {},
 'total_vector_count': 0}
```

Here the code successfully gets the right table to answer the question.

```
from transformers import pipeline, TapasTokenizer, TapasForQuestionAnswering

query = "What is the amount of the unentered transaction?"

# generate embedding for the query
xq = retriever.encode([query]).tolist()
# query pinecone index to find the table containing answer to the query
result = index.query(xq, top_k=1)

id = int(result["matches"][0]["id"])

model_name = "google/tapas-base-finetuned-wtq"
# load the tokenizer and the model from huggingface model hub
tokenizer = TapasTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = TapasForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name, local_files_only=False)
# load the model and tokenizer into a question-answering pipeline
pipe = pipeline("table-question-answering",  model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, device=device)
```

I pass the table into the table reader but the pipeline expects a string or a byte.

```
pipe(table=tables[id], query=query)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-5d351749f21b> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 pipe(table=tables[id], query=query)

15 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/pipelines/table_question_answering.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    345         pipeline_inputs = self._args_parser(*args, **kwargs)
    346 
--> 347         results = super().__call__(pipeline_inputs, **kwargs)
    348         if len(results) == 1:
    349             return results[0]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py in __call__(self, inputs, num_workers, batch_size, *args, **kwargs)
   1119                     inputs, num_workers, batch_size, preprocess_params, forward_params, postprocess_params
   1120                 )
-> 1121                 outputs = list(final_iterator)
   1122                 return outputs
   1123             else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/pipelines/pt_utils.py in __next__(self)
    122 
    123         # We're out of items within a batch
--> 124         item = next(self.iterator)
    125         processed = self.infer(item, **self.params)
    126         # We now have a batch of "inferred things".

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/pipelines/pt_utils.py in __next__(self)
    122 
    123         # We're out of items within a batch
--> 124         item = next(self.iterator)
    125         processed = self.infer(item, **self.params)
    126         # We now have a batch of "inferred things".

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    631                 # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    632                 self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 633             data = self._next_data()
    634             self._num_yielded += 1
    635             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    675     def _next_data(self):
    676         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 677         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    678         if self._pin_memory:
    679             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     49                 data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     50             else:
---> 51                 data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     52         else:
     53             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     49                 data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     50             else:
---> 51                 data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     52         else:
     53             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/pipelines/pt_utils.py in __getitem__(self, i)
     17     def __getitem__(self, i):
     18         item = self.dataset[i]
---> 19         processed = self.process(item, **self.params)
     20         return processed
     21 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/pipelines/table_question_answering.py in preprocess(self, pipeline_input, sequential, padding, truncation)
    374         if query is None or query == "":
    375             raise ValueError("query is empty")
--> 376         inputs = self.tokenizer(table, query, return_tensors=self.framework, truncation=truncation, padding=padding)
    377         inputs["table"] = table
    378         return inputs

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/tapas/tokenization_tapas.py in __call__(self, table, queries, answer_coordinates, answer_text, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
    669             )
    670         else:
--> 671             return self.encode_plus(
    672                 table=table,
    673                 query=queries,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/tapas/tokenization_tapas.py in encode_plus(self, table, query, answer_coordinates, answer_text, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
   1035             )
   1036 
-> 1037         return self._encode_plus(
   1038             table=table,
   1039             query=query,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/tapas/tokenization_tapas.py in _encode_plus(self, table, query, answer_coordinates, answer_text, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
   1086             )
   1087 
-> 1088         table_tokens = self._tokenize_table(table)
   1089         query, query_tokens = self._get_question_tokens(query)
   1090 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/tapas/tokenization_tapas.py in _tokenize_table(self, table)
   1385             tokenized_row = []
   1386             for cell in row:
-> 1387                 tokenized_row.append(self.tokenize(cell))
   1388             tokenized_rows.append(tokenized_row)
   1389 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py in tokenize(self, text, **kwargs)
    513             ]
    514             pattern = r"(" + r"|".join(escaped_special_toks) + r")|" + r"(.+?)"
--> 515             text = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: m.groups()[0] or m.groups()[1].lower(), text)
    516 
    517         # split_special_tokens: empty `no_split_token`

/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    207     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    208     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 209     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    210 
    211 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

```
type(tables[id])
```

Output

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

The tables were formatted as follows:

```
def _preprocess_tables(tables: list):
    processed = []
    # loop through all tables
    for table in tables:
        # convert the table to csv and
        processed_table = "\n".join([table.to_csv(index=False)])
        # add the processed table to processed list
        processed.append(processed_table)
    return processed

tables = [positions, transactions]

# format all the dataframes in the tables list
processed_tables = _preprocess_tables(tables)

# display the formatted table
processed_tables[1]
```

Output

```
Status,Date,AssetID,sec_type,Units,Amount,trans_type\nEntered,06/23/2022,999LP999,GENERIC_LP_DPV,1,0,BUY\nEntered,07/14/2022,888LP888,GENERIC_LP_DPV,1,0,BUY\nEntered,09/30/2022,777LP777,GENERIC_LP_DPV,1,0,BUY\nEntered,10/12/2022,555LP555,GENERIC_LP_DPV,1,0,BUY\nUnentered,12/15/2022,999LP999,GENERIC_LP_DPV,0,50000,RCAP\nEntered,07/24/2023,999LP999,GENERIC_LP_DPV,0,-25000,CAPC\nEntered,03/07/2024,888LP888,GENERIC_LP_DPV,0,-25000,CAPC\nEntered,04/30/2024,777LP777,GENERIC_LP_DPV,0,25000,RCAP\nEntered,05/22/2024,555LP555,GENERIC_LP_DPV,0,25000,RCAP\n
```